# NullPointerException during Parameter Variation Experiment with agent statistics

Tags: anylogic

at the start of the experiment, I get the error message '*Error in the model during iteration 5* (numbers vary between 2, 3, and 5)' and it points to the agent-statistics Dataset from main that I try to add to a histogram dataset in my experiment. Is it possible that somewhere I try to collect agent statistics before the agents are initialized?

To be more precise about my setting: My root agent for the experiment is an agent called 'firms'. Within that agent, I have added the dataset 'DSUsers', which simply collects the agent statistics (item.inState(Firm....)) located in the main agent. The dataset DSUsers is what I try to add to the histogram dataset 'data' for the parameter variation experiment with the settings described below. (unfortunately, I can't add screenshots yet, I am too young a member...)

In the experiment, I use the following setup:

Before simulation run:
`data.reset();`

After simulation run:
`data.add(root.DSUsers);`

DSUsers being the dataset that I collect from the main agent-statistics. The top-level agent of my experiment is not the main agent (could that be a problem?). 
So the process looks something like this:
Collecting agent statistics in main -> Using a dataset on the agent-level which collects the statistics from main and stores it -> importing this dataset to a histogram dataset in the experiment.

I get a large error message in the console, the first error pointing to

```
  private double _DSPledgeUsers_YValue() {
    return 
get_Main().firms.NPledgeUsers()
;}
```

Comment: Can you clarify on this: "The top-level agent of my experiment is not the main agent (could that be a problem?).". Are you saying that "data" does not live on Main? Note that "root" does not automatically refer to Main but to your top-level agent as defined in the experiment properties. Also, some screenshots would be helpful, a bit hard to follow your setup

Comment: Sure Benjamin, thank you! My root agent for the experiment is an agent called 'firms'. Within that agent, I have added the dataset 'DSUsers', which simply collects the agent statistics (item.inState(Firm....)) located in the main agent. The dataset DSUsers is what I try to add to the histogram dataset 'data' for the parameter variation experiment with the settings described above. Just let me know when you need more details. I will add some screenshots shortly. Many thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately I can't add screenshots yet, I am too young a member...

Comment: You can upload elsewhere and share the link here. Re your prob: does it work when you run an equivalent simulation experiment several times with different random seeds? Since it currently fails at different runs, somehow the different random seeds are causing the issue sometimes, but not always. If you can reproduce with a single simulation run, it will be much easier for you to track the error

Comment: Thanks for your help, @Benjamin! Here the link to some screenshots: [Link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/2o2wnixp412jsns/AABT9Aeg87vZPUMaO6HW7NA5a?dl=0) 
I am not sure if I understand you correctly, the problem remains when I choose 'random seed' instead of 'fixed seed' in the randomness property of the experiment...

Comment: Create a "Simulation" experiment and run it several times with different seed numbers until you hit the same error. Then you can investigate easier because you can check the model while it is broken

Comment: @Benjamin, after trying the simulation experiment, it hits the error immediately when using seed number 1... It seems that I am stuck in the first state of the statechart when running the simulation experiment

Comment: alright, now do some detailed error investigation, figure out exactly what causes the error and report back ;-)

Comment: @Benjamin, is it possible that by creating a Dataset in an agent, the agent's states in the statechart update automatically at each timestep (which is usually done by adding an internal transition, as far as I know)? I think this could cause the problem, because in one state, I only need the state to update once in a while...

Comment: I don't think so, no. But you can easily test it by building a small example model, can't you? ;-)

Comment: Yes I did, and it works! This time, the dataset is located not in the agent, but in main. Surprisingly, this seems to work...

Comment: How about you answer your own question below for future users to learn from it? Glad to have pushed you along :D

Comment: Done, thanks for the help @Benjamin. As someone who only gets started in Anylogic, I guess I need to be pushed :D

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem-maker, however, I am not sure why it works:

Somehow the dataset I created in the agent caused all of the agents' states in the statechart to automatically update on every time step. This was a problem in my model because some states were supposed to update only occasionally. So I simply moved the dataset to main.

I do not want to speculate, but if you encounter the same problem, check the location of your datasets!

Comment: this may happen if you have conditional transitions and if that is how you solved the problem, your model is probably still incorrect in ways you haven't seen yet

Comment: @Felipe, yes I use quite a few conditional transitions. Could you be more specific on that? Thanks!

Comment: Just avoid conditional transitions. They always cause hidden problems, eat performance and can be replaced by messsages always. Just avoid them :-)

Comment: Thanks @Benjamin, can you give me a hint how I could replace them with messages? E.g. how could I realise the condition randomTrue(0.1) or time()<50 with a message?
I have quite a few of those...

Comment: Use events with the same conditions. When they trigger, you send a message to the statechart to trigger the transition. It is *MUCH* better and safer to do that, trust me :-)