# How to fix the 'Error in the model during iteration' in anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I've built a model in which a fleet of trucks delivers multiple orders to different customers. This model works fine when I perform one simulation experiment. However, when I try to run a parameter variation, the following error occurs:  'Error in the model during iteration x'. A snapshot of that particular error can be found in [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRlOJ.png).

A question about this topic is earlier asked here:

[NullPointerException during Parameter Variation Experiment with agent statistics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59252861/nullpointerexception-during-parameter-variation-experiment-with-agent-statistics)

I have tried the tips given in that post but none of them seems to solve the problem.

- I have replaced all the conditional transitions with messages in my state chart (see figure).
- My data sets are stored in the database, so that cannot be the problem.

I can't get my head around why the model works with some seed values and with some not. I understand that finding the modelling flaw from just the snapshot is hard, but any tips on how I could find the mistake could be helpful.

PS: I have the learning edition so there is no debugger
[image: snapshot of the statechart]

Edit:
The error happens at a specific line of code written in the transitions pointing towards the state from the state "movingToClient1". The line that seems to cause the error is:

```
   Order order = orderStore.myOrdercollection.get(0);
```

the iterations seem to work. However, I need it to be equal to one (to specifically measure certain KPIs of the last route). Hopefully, this helps in finding a solution.

[image: Snapshot of the error]

Comment: does the NPE error point you to some code lines with blue links in the red error text? If yes, try to follow those leads and report back to where the error actually comes from :)

Comment: I have added a snapshot of the error to the question. To the best of my understanding, It seems to me that there is a reference to an empty collection in my model.

Comment: Yes. But check the errors in the console (within the AnyLogic IDE, not the running mode). You will see blue links to actual code where it says "java:503". This will show you exactly the place and you can tell us :)

Comment: I just saw your YT video and understand what you mean. I have edited the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the insight given by Felipe and Benjamin, I found the problem in my model. My model starts with an import order with a specific arrival rate of one in a source block. The rate of 1 is equivalent to exponentially distributed interarrival time with mean = 1/ratedefined (https://anylogic.help/library-reference-guides/process-modeling-library/source.html). This means that it is possible for some seed values that the orders are generated at the same time. Therefore, changing the setting from 'rate' to 'interarrival time' solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely thing to cause the problem is that your arraylist called collectionOfOrders is missused.

so at some point on the "on enter" of one of your states, you do :

```
collectionOfOrders.get(something)
```

when collectionOfOrders is actually empty.

sometimeswhat happens is that multiple things happen at the same time in your model, and when you ask if `collectionOfOrders==1`, another of your truck agents does the same and they both return true, which means that one of them will get the issue.

This happens only with certain seeds, because it occurs with a very low probability.

This is my guess, with the current information provided

Comment: That might be it! The method Benjamin proposed indeed indicates that get(something) line (real code is added to the question). do you have an idea on how to reduce/eliminate the chance of this happening?

Comment: it depends on your problem, but you can use link to agents instead of the arraylist, that way, you first connect your truck to the order, and check if no other truck is connected to that order before connecting it... then you can be safe